# Django save aggregation in master/detail (many to one relationship)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, aggregation, django-signals

I have two models, *Order* and *OrderRow* (1:n). What I would like is when something changes on the OrderRow (added, removed, price change, etc.) that that "effect" is calculated to the parent Order. In this case, sum the total of all the *OrderRow* in *Order*.

The *OrderRow* (a `admin.TabularInline` subclass) is setup as `inlines` on *Order*.

I did implement the `django.db.models.signals.post_save` but the problem here is that the *Order* `post_save` is fired **before** the *OrderRow* updates.

Is there any nice way (besides implementing a db trigger) for updating this the 'django-way' ?

All this under Django Admin

Comment: You can attach `post_save` to OrderRow instead of Order. Whenever an order row updates, get all order rows like `order_row.order.orderrow_set.all`, perform calculations and update order accordingly.

Comment: @NafeesAnwar thanks, I understand that. But it's very inefficient. The problem is when you create an order with 10 rows, it gets fired 10x. Not truly elegant 